# ¿Cómo hago para crear carpetas dentro de una carpeta colocándole de nombre el numero respectivo?

Tags: python, os

```
import os
from pathlib import Path, PurePath

os.getcwd()
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\LABORATORIO E2\Documents')  # Ubicación principal
os.getcwd()
print(os.getcwd())
primero = "Carpeta"
segundo = "Carpeta1"
for i in range(1, 101, 1):
    ubicacionp = primero + str(i)
    Path(ubicacionp).mkdir()
    for o in range(1, 11, 1):
        ubicacion2 = ubicacionp + \
                     Path(ubicacion2.mkdir()) + str(o)
```

Me quedé hasta aquí, no se si hay otra forma de resolverlo mas sencilla o así es la única manera.

El resultado sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener este resultado debes hacer varios cambios en el código. Puedes eliminar la importación de la clase `PurePath` ya que no la utilizas. Lo otro es hacer la concatenación de forma correcta para lograr el resultado deseado. Puedes hacer uso de la función `input()` para hacer el programa más interactivo.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('./root')
print(os.getcwd())

carpetas = int(input("Ingrese el número de carpetas: "))
subcarpetas = int(input("Ingrese el número de subcarpetas: "))

for i in range(1, carpetas + 1):
    ubicacion = os.getcwd()
    Path(ubicacion + '/' + str(i)).mkdir()
    for j in range(1, subcarpetas + 1):
        Path(ubicacion + '/' + str(i) + '/' + str(i) + '.' + str(j)).mkdir()
```

Comment: Me funciono de maravilla, ¡te lo agradezco mucho!

Comment: Desperdicias el potencial de `Path`, lo usas de forma incorrecta. Este modulo ayuda a manejar las rutas, la concatenación de rutas se hace mediante el operador `/`, lo que evita colocar explícitamente el *slash* o *backslashs* que cambia según el S.O. Tu código mejorado quedaría así: `path = Path(ubicacion) / str(i); path.mkdir()` y en el segundo for: `path = Path(ubicacion) / str(i) / str(i) / f".{j}; path.mkdir()`

Comment: incluso puedes simplificar todo un poco. El primer `for` lo dejas así: `path = Path(ubicacion) / str(i); path.mkdir()` y en el segundo colocas `path_ = path / f"{i}.{j}"; path_.mkdir()`

Comment: Todo programa puede ser mejorado, esta solución esta creada a partir del ejemplo compartido, el objetivo no es hacer un programa nuevo, sino resolver las dificultades que presenta el ya existente, le invito a que comparta su solución o sugerir una edición con los cambios :)

Comment: @Christian acabe de redactar una respuesta solo utilizando el modulo pathlib pero jaja viendo tu comentario tienes razon en cuanto a los *slash* no optimice esa parte, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es totalmente innecesario importar el modulo **os**,  ya que `pathlib` nos brinda lo mejor del manejo del sistema operativo siendo nuestro mejor aliado cuando se trata de manipular archivos o carpeta dentro de nuestro sistema operativo. Teniendo muchas ventajas con respecto al modulo `os`, una de las diferencias las podemos notar en el tipo de dato que genera cada modulo.

Anexo una lectura de la importacia de utilizar `pathlib` con respecto a `os`. [Don’t Use Python OS Library Any More When Pathlib Can Do](https://towardsdatascience.com/dont-use-python-os-library-any-more-when-pathlib-can-do-141fefb6bdb5)

Por otro lado hare uso del metodo `join()` este nos trae ventajas de optimización con respecto a la concatenacion hecha con el operador `+`. [Do Not Use “+” to Join Strings in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/do-not-use-to-join-strings-in-python-f89908307273)

Por lo que la soluciòn quedaria asì:

```
import pathlib

def concatenar(ruta,i,j):
    ruta = str(pathlib.Path(ruta))
    lista = [ruta,'/', str(i),'/', str(i), '.', str(j)]
    ruta_nueva = ''.join(lista)
    return ruta_nueva #retornamos la ruta

ruta = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute() # Obtiene el directorio actual
carpetas = int(input("Ingrese el número de carpetas: "))
subcarpetas = int(input("Ingrese el número de subcarpetas: "))

for i in range(1, carpetas + 1):
    archivo = str(pathlib.Path(ruta))
    fullpath = pathlib.Path(archivo + '/' + str(i)).mkdir()
    for j in range(1, subcarpetas + 1):
        pathlib.Path(concatenar(ruta,i,j)).mkdir()
```

### Nota:

Como podemos observar la soluciòn es un poco `mas larga` pero seria la manera correcta a nivel de optimizaciòn, buenas practicas y estadanres.

Comment: Obviamente lo que faltó fue usar el operador `/` para concatenar las rutas. Además hay que recordar que los objetos `Path` implementan el método `__str__` por lo que cualquier operación que necesite de un string hará esta conversión implicitamente. La línea de la variable `fullpath` podría quedar así `pathlib.Path(ruta / str(i)).mkdir()`. Además, la variable `archivo` no es necesaria (aparte que puede ir fuera del ciclo), la puedes eliminar ya que por algo ya tienes a `ruta`, que si mal no recuerdo sigue siendo un objeto `Path`.

Comment: @Christian buenas observaciones ¡Las tendré en cuenta!